# Why Nullable<T> is treated special by PropertyInfo.SetValue

Tags: c#, reflection, type-conversion

While implementing a struct similar to `Nullable<T>` I've found that `PropertyInfo.SetValue` treats `Nullable` type differently then others. 
For Nullable property  it can set value of underlying type

```
foo.GetType().GetProperty("NullableBool").SetValue(foo, true);
```

but for custom  type it throws

> System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'SomeType' cannot be converted to type NullableCase.CopyOfNullable 1[SomeType]

even if all conversion operators are overridden same way as in original `Nullable<T>`

Code to reproduce:

```
   using System;

namespace NullableCase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Copy of Nullable from .Net source code 
    /// without unrelated methodts for brevity
    /// </summary>    
    public struct CopyOfNullable<T> where T : struct
    {
        private bool hasValue;
        internal T value;

        public CopyOfNullable(T value)
        {
            this.value = value;
            this.hasValue = true;
        }

        public bool HasValue
        {            
            get
            {
                return hasValue;
            }
        }

        public T Value
        {
            get
            {
                if (!hasValue)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
                }
                return value;
            }
        }

        public static implicit operator CopyOfNullable<T>(T value)
        {
            return new CopyOfNullable<T>(value);
        }

        public static explicit operator T(CopyOfNullable<T> value)
        {
            return value.Value;
        }

    }


    class Foo
    {
        public Nullable<bool> NullableBool { get; set; }
        public CopyOfNullable<bool> CopyOfNullablBool { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Foo foo = new Foo();

            foo.GetType().GetProperty("NullableBool").SetValue(foo, true);
            foo.GetType().GetProperty("CopyOfNullablBool").SetValue(foo, true); //here we get ArgumentException 
        }
    }
}
```

Why does `PropertyInfo.SetValue` fails for `CopyOfNullable` type and passes for `Nullable<T>`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Nullable<T>` has special support within the CLR type system to automatically convert from `T`.

In fact, it is impossible to have a boxed instance of `Nullable<T>`; nullable values box to either to underlying value or an actual null.

This is one of the very few magical types in the BCL; it is impossible to duplicate.

Comment: Where else does it have this special support?

Comment: You mean where else in the CLR is there special support for `Nullable<T>`, or what other types does the CLR have special support for?

Comment: @DenisPalnitsky: This is more C# than the CLR, but the `decimal` type does not support `const`; `decimal` is not a primitive type in the CLR.  The compiler fakes `const` support (using `readonly`), though this is a slightly leaky abstraction.  [Jon Skeet explains](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/08/22/when-is-a-constant-not-a-constant-when-its-a-decimal/).

Comment: @Brian: In fact, for a list of a of _all_ types that the C# compiler has special knowledge of, see http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/WellKnownTypes.cs,502a1cb96c6a4656.  Again, that's completely separate from the CLR.

Comment: @SLaks Where else can we expect this kind of special support?

Comment: Also I'm curious about the reason why it was introduced.

Comment: @DenisPalnitsky: All of the primitive types, `Array`, some Reflectiony things, RealProxy, marshalling types, some others.  For more, explore the reference source.

Answer (score 1):

When you call .SetValue(), the call tree is as follows:

- System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object
  value, Object[] index)
- System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object
  value, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index,
  CultureInfo culture)
- System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
  invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
- System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj,
  BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters,
  CultureInfo culture)
- System.Reflection.MethodBase.CheckArguments(Object[] parameters,
  Binder binder, BindingFlags invokeAttr, CultureInfo culture, Signature sig)
- System.RuntimeType.**CheckValue**(Object value, Binder
  binder, CultureInfo culture, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
- System.RuntimeType.TryChangeType(Object value, Binder binder,
  CultureInfo culture, Boolean needsSpecialCast) **[This only gets called when you use your custom type]**

Unfortunately, when the call tree gets to [`RuntimeType.CheckValue`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/rttype.cs,ae7c1045e02d18b1) it checks if the object is an instance of the type (in this case Bool).

```
    RuntimeType runtimeType;
        if (this.IsInstanceOfType(value))
        {
            Type type = null;
            RealProxy realProxy = RemotingServices.GetRealProxy(value);
            type = (realProxy == null ? value.GetType() : realProxy.GetProxiedType());
            if (type == this || !RuntimeTypeHandle.IsValueType(this))
            {
                return value;
            }
            return RuntimeType.AllocateValueType(this, value, true);
        }
        if (!base.IsByRef)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                return value;
            }
            if (this == RuntimeType.s_typedRef)
            {
                return value;
            }
        }
```

A Nullable will pass the logic check as `IsInstanceOfType(value)` returns true, and the framework will call [`RemotingServices.GetRealProxy`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/remoting/remotingservices.cs,4d949a5c43e99512) which will allow the method to ascertain equality based on generic type values.

As we know, Nullable types are special and have extra language support (think of how you can use `int?` instead of `Nullable<int>`). When your custom type traverses this equality check, it will not be considered an equal instance and will instead continue down to the logic tree, treating it as a separate type, and invoking `System.RuntimeType.TryChangeType`

If we delve into the source code further in `IsInstanceOfType`, what we find is that `RuntimeTypeHandle.CanCastTo` is used to determine equality, and it delegates the typing to the VM (in this case, Nullable types are baked into the VM based on version, as Nullable in the framework is decorated as `[System.Runtime.Versioning.NonVersionable]`)

```
   // For runtime type, let the VM decide.
        if (fromType != null)
        {
            // both this and c (or their underlying system types) are runtime types
            return RuntimeTypeHandle.CanCastTo(fromType, this);
        }
```

Hopefully what this tells you is that `Nullable` Types have special support in the framework which can't be replicated. Since Reflection utilizes this support, you won't be able to duplicate some of the nuances of `Nullable<T>`

Comment: Are you saying that `int?` is not translated by the C# language into `Nullable<int>`, and that it's a CLR function to do that?

Comment: @ClickRick I have reviewed the [Roslyn Open Source Compiler Code](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) and from what I can tell, the compiler does not compile `int?` as `Nullable<Int>`, they are left as separate syntax nodes. In fact, if you decompile an app which uses both `int?` and `Nullable<int>`, you can see that the syntax is left as is by the compiler.This leads me to believe that `?` is a CLR construct.

Comment: @MariusDornean: That's completely wrong.  `int?` is syntactic sugar for `Nullable<T>`.  The Roslyn syntax tree always preserves raw syntax, but the semantic model will have the same type.

Comment: In fact, you can see the Roslyn compiler code that actually turns `T?` into `Nullable<T>`: http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Binder/Binder_Symbols.cs,292

Comment: @SLaks Thanks for clarifying that!

Comment: `have extra language support` you mean extra framework support; this has nothing to do with `int?` shorthand.

Comment: `NonVersionable` isn't actually relevant at all; it's just about field layout and cross-version ngen.  http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/versioning/NonVersionableAttribute.cs